# Reading formula and dual space

Tags: linear-algebra

$E$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $K$ and $E^*$ its dual ($\phi$ is a linear form)

Below one propertie :

$\boxed{x\in E, x=0\iff \forall \phi\in E^*,\langle\phi,x\rangle=0}$

I've got a problem of interpretation of the $\Longleftarrow$ propertie

$\bigg[\underbrace{(\forall \phi\in E^*,\langle\phi,x\rangle=0)\implies x=0}_{\text{the ($\Longleftarrow$) propertie} \quad(1)}\bigg]\iff\bigg[\underbrace{(\forall \phi \in E^*\ \ \phi(x)=0)\implies x=0}_{\text{interpretation from 1}\quad(2)}\bigg] \iff \bigg[\underbrace{\forall \phi \in E^*,\quad \ker\phi=\{0\}}_{\text{interpretation from 2}\quad(3)}\bigg]$

But if $\dim E\geq2\implies \ker\phi\neq\{0\}$, there is a contradiction, what is wrong with my interpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last interpretation is wrong, it should be $$\forall \phi \in E^*, \, x \in \ker \phi.$$ This clearly implies $x=0$; indeed, if $x \neq 0$ we have a functional $x^* \in E^*$ such that $x^*(x)=1$: just extend $x$ to a basis of $E$ and take the dual basis.

Comment: Thanks I have got problem of interpretation because of the brackets, written like that that is better $\forall x\in E,\quad \bigg[(\forall \phi\in E^*,\langle\phi,x\rangle=0)\implies x=0\bigg]$